# Make a http server accessible in a remote network through VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ppp

I have an all Linux environment.

I'm connected to a remote network through a PPP VPN tunnel. My machine at home appears to be on the same network as the remote machines through the PPP interface.

This machine hosts an HTTP server, and the remote machines can view the web page in the browser by simply entering http://10.1.2.10:80.

I would like to move the HTTP server to another machine at home. But I don't want to configure a PPP connection for it as well. I want the current machine to be the VPN gateway towards the remote network for all my local machines.

The goal is for the remote machines to be able to access the HTTP server on a local machine that is not the gateway as easily as it is right now.

I imagine I would have to configure some port forwarding on the gateway. Do you have a comprehensive guide or recommendations for that?
This could be achieved with an HTTP proxy, but it feels like an overkill solution in my case.

Maybe there are other solutions.

Any VPN software that does the job will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows
[Netsh interface portproxy commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy)
and specifically the verb
[add v4tov4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4).

An example command would be to redirect all port 80 traffic to
IP address `192.168.0.10` by running as Administrator
the command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.10 connectport=80
```

The VPN might add some complexity to the local network solution,
but that's something you will need to solve on your end.

Comment: Apparently our comments got removed lol.

Comment: Not laughing. If you still have the Linux link I gave, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider setting up a VPN based on the modern Wireguard protocol, that supersedes the older more complex approach using OpenVPN.

A popular commercial VPN based on Wireguard that is easy to set up, can punch through most firewalls, and is free for personal use is [Tailscale](https://tailscale.ocm)

Search Google for Nebula, Headscale, Netmaker, Netbird, and Yggdrasil for more open alternatives that may still meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll look into those, and I like wireguard. Actually I don't mind the difficulty of setting this up. It's fine with iptables and similar, it's just that I can't find a comprehensive tutorial that accomplishes what I'm trying to do.